# Are there no CC cameras near/inside the storage unit in 'You', Season 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, you

In the show 'You', Season 2, we see that Joe/Will uses a locker/storage system to build his cage in it (where he can store people at his will). He locks up the original 'Will' and eventually another person in it..

My question is: don't storage units have CC cameras inside? Or at least on the outside? It just seems all top convenient for Joe to keep shoving people into his storage unit without any CC cameras capturing him. (I know that Delilah was already in his storage unit when he put her in his cage, so that may not count, but what about a knocked out original Will Bettelhiem?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually is one security camera at the entrance of the building, it even gets its own shot around 31:40 into the 9th episode. However, it appears to be broken, which may be done by Joe (offscreen) or may be the reason he chose that storage unit to begin with.

Comment: hey i must have missed this !! rewatched. thank you !!